# Prove a cancellation law for multiplication of numbers that is for 2 natural numbers b and c that if some natural number a we knew ab = ac prove b =c

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question also states that we dont have division and we have not proven any cancellation law, nor do we have 0.

I thought of proving this by induction:

Base Case: $n=1$.  $b$ x $1$ = $c$ x $1$ implies $ b = c$

I am stuck on how to do the induction part?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Peano axioms, and in particular with the recursive definition of multiplication?

Comment: If so, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875553/multiplication-cancellation-property-by-peano-axioms

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365019 , are you asking part c) of this question?

Comment: Please use the body of the Question (not the title only) to give a self-contained presentation of the problem you want help with.  Here the mention of what you are *not* allowed to use invites guesswork for Readers as to what *is* allowed.